# How to download file by sharing link with Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

There is a file with a sharing link within a google workspace, and a service account with domain wide delegation enabled for the workspace. How to download the file by the sharing link using Google Drive API?

Details: I have google a workspace with  a file shared within the workspace: permission `Anyone in this group with this link can view` this group means the workspace here. And I have a `Service Account` with domain wide delegation granted for the workspace above. I can iterate through users (Admin SDK), and their files (Drive API) and even download a file if it's owner's email and file googleId are known. But I don't see native, straightforward way to download a file through the API  if I have sharing link only.

Comment: Hi! It would be useful if you can provide more context about your scenario, for example, how are you using the Drive API? Anyway, to download a file you need the file id (contained in the the sharing link) and [Download files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#python). I suggest you to show what you have tried and where you have problems.

Comment: @fullfine please see details above.  _to download a file you need the file id_  and also a user's email to impersonate it

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

*Your challenge has two parts: create the Drive service for a service account and download a file with this service*

### Explanation

Your challenge has two parts: create the [Drive service](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) for a [service account](https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/guides/delegation) and [download](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#python) a file with this service.

### Code

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']

def main(user_email):
    // CREATE DRIVE SERVICE WITH SERVICE ACCOUNT
    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE_PATH,
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'])
    creds = creds.create_delegated(user_email)
    drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    // DOWNLOAD FILE
    file_id = '0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M'
    request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
    fh = io.BytesIO()
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        print "Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_email = "something@example.com"
    main(user_email)
```

### References

- [Drive API: Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python)
- [Drive API: Download files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#python)
- [Perform Google Workspace domain-wide delegation of authority](https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/guides/delegation)